# Laravel Many to Many relation Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-migrations

I'm creating a ManyToMany relationship with the Laravel framework v.5.7. So I created three migrations.

**Modules Table**

```
Schema::create('modules', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name')->unique();
    $table->integer('price');
});
```

**Plans Table**

```
Schema::create('plans', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('stripe_id')->unique();
    $table->integer('price');
    $table->integer('max_users');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

**Relation Table**

```
Schema::create('plan_modules', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('plan_id')->unsigend();
    $table->integer('module_id')->unsigend();
    // Keys
    $table->foreign('plan_id')->references('id')->on('plans')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->foreign('module_id')->references('id')->on('modules')->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

Whe I run the migration I get `General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint`.

Dose anyone has a idea what is wrong with the migrations. The default engine for mysql is set to `InnoDB`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your last migration should be as follows:

```
Schema::create('plan_modules', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->unsignedInteger('plan_id')
    $table->unsignedInteger('module_id');
    $table->foreign('plan_id')->references('id')->on('plans')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->foreign('module_id')->references('id')->on('modules')->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

Fixed the typos and you need to apply `onDelete()` to the foreign key definition and not the actual field definition.

Provided that your migration run in the same order you mentioned above, it should work.

Comment: Thank you It's working. What is the difference between  `unsignedInteger()` and `integer()->unsigned()`?

Comment: It essentially does the same thing :)

Comment: @Markus increment is an unsigned integer and it should be remembered that related field attributes must be exact the same to relational field attributes. Also try to follow Eloquent naming convention which would tell you pivot table name should be `module_plan` (check in docs why). It solves lot of headaches later, if you follow their standards.